# How can we use the deeplink information to gather sender data like mail id using Google API AppReferral

Tags: android, google-api, apprequests, google-app-invites, google-developer-tools

I am trying Application referral using this https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/ detail.

My Application requirement once receiver installed the referred Application, sender needs to get some credit like points.

But i can not get any data about sender while receiver get install the application.

Kindly please let me know how to get the sender infomation using https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/ this detail.

Answer (score 0):

The user who is receiving the invitation will know who sent the invitation from the sms or email sender information, but the receiving app will not get this data, as you point out. However, the sending app can send an app-specific identity as a query parameter of the deeplink, perhaps a game specific user id that can be used to award points.

Comment: if i have change the deep link as my application play store link i can not get invitation alert. Does you have any idea about that? please let me know. @Jim

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. Based on what I can infer from your description, you can add query parameters to your deep link without effecting your deeplink and it's ability to get an invitation alert (which I infer means match an Intent filter). For example, in the invitation builder:  .setDeepLink(Uri.parse("http://example.com/offer/free_trial_campaign?senderGameId=1234"))